# Удаленное подключение к SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Хочу удаленно подключится к SQL SERVER EXPRESS по интернету. Пересмотрел много гайдов, но так и не нашел решения. Вот мой код генерации строки подключения и открытия подключения к серверу.

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        csBuilder.UserID = "test";
        csBuilder.Password = "test123";
        csBuilder.InitialCatalog = "TestDB";
        csBuilder.DataSource = @"178.133.xxx.70";
        csBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        csBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
        csBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(csBuilder.ConnectionString);

        con.Open();
```

В Configuuration Manager настроил все что нужно, брандмауэр вырубил под корень. Перепробовал множество вариантов DataSource. Писал строку подключения вручную. Ничего не получается. В программе выдает исключение:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: [Configure the remote access Server Configuration Option](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Я думаю одна из проблемы(возможно есть и другие) - то что у вам не проброшен порт на внешку, в роутере к которому подключен комп с SQL Server, потому как я не вижу этого в перечисленных действиях.